# How to find a bijective mapping such that

Tags: elementary-set-theory

a) $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$

I'm thinking $f(x) = x-1$, because in order to get 0, it would just be 1-1. Is this correct? I can show this is a bijection because it is surjective, i.e.: $ y = x - 1 \implies x = y+ 1$ and $f(x) = f(y+1) = y+1-1 = y$ and it is injective because $f(a) = a -1 = f(b) = b-1$ and adding one to both sides yields $a = b$.

b) $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \backslash \{1,2,3,...2017\}$

I'm a bit confused on this, if I do $f(x) = x + 2017$ and I can show this is a bijection the same way. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.

Comment: Assuming that $\Bbb N$ to you is defined as being the non-negative integers, yes these are both correct (*though a bit uninspired*).  You might go into a bit more detail as to why $x=y+1$ for the first and $x=y-2017$ for the second are both valid inputs in $\Bbb N$ since for certain values of $y$ ordinarily these might not be (*e.g. if $y=100$ you don't have $y-2017$ as a natural number*).

Comment: Both your reasoning and conclusions are correct. Note that if you can prove a function is invertible then you've proved it's bijective. If you don't have this result you seem well prepared to prove it yourself.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for your point. I didn't think of that, so must I specify that y>2017? and what would be another function that would map this?

Comment: "*so must I specify that $y>2017$*"  Since $y\in \Bbb N\setminus \{1,2,3,\dots,2017\}$ it follows that $y>2017$ and it further follows that $y-2017\in\Bbb N$.  It may seem obvious but it is worth explicitly saying for this level of proof.  "*What would be another function that would map this?*" There are many, but very few are easy to write.  For an interesting-ish example, how about the function mapping the $n$'th even number to the $n$'th multiple of $3$ and mapping the $n$'th odd number to the $n$'th non-multiple of $3$, giving the sequence $1,3,2,6,4,9,5,12,7,15,8,18,10,21,11,24,\dots$

Comment: (*with appropriate offset, of course, as it is currently a function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$*)

Answer (score 1):

That would be correct.  This is a variant of the Hilbert hotel "technique", whereby you can essentially lose an extra element in (and only in) an infinite set.

As Cantor said,  "i see it but I can't believe it. "